# How can I get rid of the blank space being left on the plot panel in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This is the desired output: similar to output by subsetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm83j.jpg)

[diamond subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjooy.jpg)

I am using scale_x_discrete to set the limits of the x axis. I would like to know how to get rid of the blank space left on the panel and have the defined limits fill the entire axis.

```
myplot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity, fill = cut)) + #data
    geom_bar() + #geom
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("I1", "SI2", "VS2"),
                     name = "Clarity of Stones") #setting limits #limits
myplot
```

Comment: After some discussion it appears that your problem is not entirely reproducible, since its related to the graphical output of a session of RollApp R-Studio www.rollapp.com/launch/rstudio. You could try to contact their website to report this possible bug. For any future question i strongly recomend that you mention *from the beginning* the platform you're using, it would save us a lot of time :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @agenis , I am not very conclusive that this is a platform problem because I ran the same code using r studio on my machine with similar inconsistency; have you tried running the code on your in your local r IDE?

Comment: ok sorry i thought you only had this pb on rollapp, that was not clear to me. I tried different versions of R (3.0.2 3.0.3 3.2.3 with r-gui or r-studio 099.903). I didn't try with older versions of R-studio indeed. I was never able to reproduce your graphic :-(

Comment: and same for you what do you get when you run in R-gui not rstudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to subset your data for particular measures (clarity in this case), you should do this within the data object provided. As in:

```
ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$clarity %in% c("I1", "SI2", "VS2"),], aes(x = clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: This works fine, but I am looking for a 'within axis scale' alternative to subsetting; how to do that within the plot code without subsetting the data. But if there is none, then I guess that subsetting is the way.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand you goal in this case. Maybe if you could provide desired output i.e. particular combination of several `geom_x()` where changing axis scale makes sense.. then I could think of something else. Generally, in either case I would do the data subset, with only difference - within geom object itself.

Comment: @JohnMutuma I think your first guess way OK but there was a typo in the code (see my answer). The method suggested by A.Val does the subsetting, whereas your initial method using x `limits` needs no subsetting but prints a warning message due to the points removed: `Warning message:
Removed 31747 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count). `

Comment: Please see the link to the desired output and note the difference with the scaled output... @A.Val.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I'm blind. Where exactly is the difference apart from the ordering?

Comment: @A.Val. notice that using scale limits, there is a huge blank space in the panel, this is not there using the subsetting approach.

Comment: in r-fiddle, I note this in the console;

Comment: in r-fiddle, I note this in the console; The following object is masked from 'package:ggvis':

    resolution ..... could r-fiddle be using ggvis instead of ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably just a syntax problem since you missed a parenthesis at the end of your `limits` argument, and the name of the scale is wrongly passed as a fourth column of your X-axis. You shoud run:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("I1", "SI2", "VS2"), name = "Clarity of Stones")
```

Comment: I rectified the error. In fact the error wasn't in the original code in  R, only in the code provided here...

Comment: @JohnMutuma OK but i really don't understand how you end up with the second plot of your link... What version of ggplot do you have? Your code run in fiddle: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=RF41GZBq

Comment: clearly in r-fiddle the output is as desired. I ran the code in rollapp r studio

Comment: the problem does not come from R of the ggplot package (its version 2.1.0), but most probably from the graphical engine of RollApp R-Studio.